# ¿Cómo repito una función con diferentes elementos de un vector de caracteres?

Tags: base-de-datos, r

Puede que sea una pregunta tonta pero no he podido dar con la respuesta :(. Estoy utilizando la función rl_synonyms del paquete **rredlist** de la IUCN, la cual toma el nombre de una especie ("Panthera onca" por ejemplo, en formato de caracteres) y la función arroja los sinónimos registrados para esta especie (solo acepta una especie a la vez). Yo tengo un vector de caracteres con los nombres de 1000 especies y quisiera construir un dataframe con el nombre de las especies y sus sinónimos. He probado con el siguiente código:

```
library(rredlist)

ejemplo <- c("Panthera onca", "Tremarctos ornatus", "Dasypus novemcinctus")

for (i in ejemplo)
  {
   sinonimos = rl_synonyms(i, API)
  }
sinonimos
```

Cuando veo el resultado, solo me aparece la información de la primera o la última especie, pero no del total que busco. Agradecería mucho cualquier indicación (Perdón por lo burdo del código)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo aparece el último por que en cada iteración estas sobreescribiendo la misma variable `sinonimos`. Lo que deberías hacer es "agregar" cada salida de `rl_synonyms` a, por ejemplo, una lista:

```
sinonimos = list()
for (i in ejemplo) {
   sinonimos[[i]] = rl_synonyms(i, API)
}
```

Así, `sinonimos` será una lista dónde cada índice apunta a uno de los elementos, si te es más cómodo manejar todo como un vector puedes al final hacer:

```
vector_sinonimos = unlist(sinonimos)
```